# How to set a value by id in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have some issues in passing value upon onClick function of my button. My variable 'mode' does not update on the function that i already trigger upon onclick of the button.
I have this code;

```
var mode = '';
const goToEdit(){
 mode = 'readOnly'
}

<ButtonToolbar id="btnToolBar" mode={mode}>
 <Button variant="primary" onClick={(goToEdit() => setModalShow(true)}>
   popUp modal
 </Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing the binding wrong. Please refer to this doc here: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

And you can probably do something like this:

```js
var mode = '';
const goToEdit(){
 mode = 'readOnly'
}

<ButtonToolbar id="btnToolBar" mode={mode}>
 <Button variant="primary" onClick={(() => {goToEdit();setModalShow(true);}}>
   popUp modal
 </Button>
```

Comment: It gives me a clearer view on how to handle events!..Thanks

Comment: Please consider marking the answer Accepted if it was useful